# file_get_contents and connection refused error - MapQuest

Tags: php, connection, file-get-contents, mapquest, connection-refused

I'm getting the following error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=MYKEY&location=Chicago,IL): failed to open stream: Connection refused in /home/mysite/public_html/mapq.php on line 2

Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=MYKEY&location=Chicago,IL');
```

It'll be great if someone can let me know how this can be addressed and thanks for your time ahead.

Comment: Are you sure key is valid fot this request?

Comment: They key is valid and it returns results in browser.